# Passing float from Java to JNI, extra decimals

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a JNI application.

In the Java implementation, I have the following

```
float floatValue = 23.45f;
Object[] objArray = new Object[] { floatValue } ;
```

When I call a native method, passing over my object array, and in CPP I do the following:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_my_method(JNIEnv * env, jobject objInstance, jobjectArray objArray){
    jclass floatClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Float"); 
    jmethodID floatMethod = env->GetMethodID(floatClass, "floatValue", "()F");
    jobject obj = env->GetObjectArrayElement(objArray, 0);
    jfloat val = env->CallFloatMethod(obj, floatMethod);
    printf("JNI received float value: %f\n",val);
}
```

It prints:

```
JNI received float value: 23.450001
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Floats don't have decimal places. They have binary places. Your float never had the value 23.45 in the first place. You need to read up in floating-point.

Comment: But nor is its value 23.450001.  The difference comes down to how Java chooses which "nearby" decimal to print for a given float, and how C++ does it.  The two algorithms are different.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a good study for the mathematically inclined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three different ways of looking at what a `float` represents.

- You can say that a `float` is an exact value, which is the number that the 0's and 1's that make up the `float` represent in binary.  A `float` is made up of a mantissa, an exponent and a sign bit, and you can do the mathematics to turn those 0's and 1's into an actual number.  This is the most common way of looking at a `float`, and most people would consider it the most correct way.
- You can think of a `float` as representing a range of values - basically all the numbers that closer to that `float` than to any other.  This is useful when you've used a `float` for measuring something.
- You can think of a `float` as representing the particular number within that range, which has the shortest decimal expansion.  This idea is fraught with problems, but it has influenced the way Java works with floating point.

So consider the number `x = 23.450000762939453125`.  This number happens to be represented exactly by a `float`, which I'll call *f* - that is, break *f* into its mantissa and exponent, do the calculation, and `x` will come out.

The next number below `x` that has can be represented exactly by a float is `x - h = 23.4499988555908203125`.  And the next number above `x` that can be represented exactly by a float is `x + h = 23.4500026702880859375`.  I've just used `h` to denote the gap between consecutive `float` numbers around this magnitude.

Now, if you have any number in the range `x - h / 2 = 23.44999980926513671875` up to `x + h / 2 = 23.45000171661376953125`, then the closest `float` to your number will be *f*.  So that is the range of numbers that are represented by *f* - and of course,  `x` is right in the middle of this range.

You'll notice that `23.45` is in that range, and so is `23.450001`.  What that means is that if you take the Java `float` literal `23.45F`, its value is in fact *f*.  The same is true of the Java `float` literal `23.450001F`.  And that's why the expression `(23.45F == 23.450001F)` works out to be `true`.

Now, when we try to print this `float` number *f*, things start to get different between C++ and Java.

- In C++, the default way of printing a `float` is to find the number that it represents exactly, and round it to six decimal places.  So what you get is `x` rounded to six decimal places, which of course is `23.450001`.
- In Java, the default way of printing a `float` is to find the number within the represented range, with the shortest decimal expansion.  In other words, Java will look for the number between `x - h / 2` and `x + h / 2` that it can write with the smallest number of decimal places.  This number is `23.45`.

So any C++ program will show *f* as `23.450001`, unless  you specifically instruct the program to show it differently.  Any Java program will show *f* as `23.45`, unless you specifically instruct the program to show it differently.  But it's all the same `float`.

Comment: Only the first option you list is correct.  Floating-point arithmetic is inconsistent with the other options; the intervals get wider whenever you do arithmetic under your second option, and the shortest decimal expansion of the sum of two floats does not always agree with the sum of the shortest decimal expansions.  Also, the first option leads naturally to the idea of backward error analysis---you're solving a problem whose data are very close to the data of the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @tmyklebu I say nothing here about doing arithmetic with floats, so your objections about widening intervals and about the sum of two floats not agreeing with the sum of the shortest decimal expansions are both true, but both irrelevant.  My point here is that in the process of working with floats or doubles, we typically hold all three of these models in our heads at some point, and we need to understand the differences between them, and why neither one of them is really a complete picture of what's going on.  The second and third "options" are there to illustrate why `23.45` is not in ...

Comment: ... fact numerically equal to the number 23.45.  To argue that one of these three mental models is correct and the other two are not is missing the point entirely.

Comment: Well, I write lots of floating-point code.  I never have the second or third models you list in my head because they're wrong, so I'm not sure who the "we" is that typically holds the other two in its head.  If you're referring to common misconceptions, though, you're absolutely right that the latter two are common misconceptions.

Comment: @tmyklebu Not at all.  If you want to discuss what a "float" actually IS, it's no more than 32 different voltages inside your computer's RAM.  But it's useful because it represents stuff.  If I have a float value, and it displays 23.45 when I print it in Java, then it represents 23.45, even though it also represents 23.450000762939453125 and a whole range of other numbers.  To claim that it's wrong to believe that this float represents 23.45 is like one of the [six blind men with the elephant](http://www.constitution.org/col/blind_men.htm) insisting to the other five that there's only one ...

Comment: ... correct opinion about what an elephant is.  In the OP's case, it's useful to see this float as representing 23.45, because that's the value that he fed into his JNI interface.  It's also useful to see it as representing 23.450001, because that's the value that his C++ program printed.  It's not quite so useful to see it as representing 23.450000762939453125 because he never actually did any arithmetic with this number, so the exact decimal value of the binary expansion of this value was entirely irrelevant to him.

Comment: It's "useful" to have incorrect mental models only insofar as they allow you to form testable hypotheses that you can refute in order to correct your mental model.  Also, your analogy to the elephant story does not appear to make any sense.

Comment: Why are you being so closed minded about this?  There is nothing incorrect about saying that a float represents a range of values.  There is nothing incorrect about saying that a particular float represents 23.45.  You disagree, fine.  Leave your downvote in place.  But the OP wanted an explanation as to why he saw 23.45 at one end of his process, and 23.450001 at the other end.  I have explained it correctly.  The fact that you refuse to leave your end of the elephant is no doubt irrelevant to the OP.  @tmyklebu

Comment: I don't think I'm being 'closed-minded" by rejecting things that are demonstrably false.  The top third of your answer promotes misconceptions, the middle third is an excellent description of the necessary background, and the bottom third answers the direct question correctly.  Saying that a particular float represents 23.45 is analogous to saying the int 23 represents 23.45; it's fundamentally wrong-headed.

Answer (score 1):

`23.45 == 23.450001` so there's no problem.

If you're surprised about that equivalence, it's true both in C++ and in Java regardless of JNI. It follows from the limited precision of the common underlying floating point type.

Comment: Or more correctly `23.45F == 23.450001F`.  In both C++ and Java, literals that have decimal points but don't have `F` or `f` are interpreted as `double`, not `float`; and technically, that makes your assertion false.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a cosmetic solution, you can always change the output 
precision of printf() by changing:

```
printf("JNI received float value: %f\n",val);
```

to something like:

```
printf("JNI received float value: %f.4\n",val);
```

Comment: Using a double only changes the available precision. It doesn't remove the underlying problem.

Comment: @EJP - I was able to reproduce this symptom using float but did not see any precision issues when I moved to double.  But thanks for the info, I'll remove that suggestion from my comment.